# How to open form by string name?

Tags: c#, winforms

If i get string value from textbox and my Form name is same string value from textbox.
How to open this form ?

```
string formAAA = textbox.text; // "AAA"
```

I need to open form 'AAA';

Answer (score 7):

```
   string formtocall = "blabla";

    var form = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("namespace." + formtocall)) as Form;

    form.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: If you think this answered your question then please mark it as the answer to help others find the correct answer quickly and also give Hüseyin the credits.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use reflection.

Opening a form is creating an instance of it, you need to create the instance and show it.

You are going to need the  name of the form and its namespace.

```
string formName= textbox.Text;
string namespaceName = "MyNamespace.MyInternalNamespace";
```

Then you create your instance with activator.

```
var frm= Activator.CreateInstance(namespaceName, formName) as Form;
```

And then you just need to show the form

```
frm.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below:

```
    private Type[] GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly assembly, string nameSpace)
            {
                return assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => String.Equals(t.Namespace, nameSpace, StringComparison.Ordinal)).ToArray();
            }

            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
//Get all types
                Type[] typelist = GetTypesInNamespace(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(), "loopClasses");
                for (int i = 0; i < typelist.Length; i++)
                {//Loop on them 
                    if (typelist[i].BaseType == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Form) && typelist[i].Name == textbox.text)
                    {//if windows form and the name is match

//Create Instance and show it
                        Form tmp =(Form) Activator.CreateInstance(typelist[i]);
                        //MessageBox.Show(typelist[i].Name);
                        tmp.Show();
                    }
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this:

```
Form GetFormByName(string name)
    {
        System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly =System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        foreach(Type type in myAssembly.GetTypes())
        {
            if (type.BaseType!=null&& type.BaseType.FullName == "System.Windows.Forms.Form")
            {
                if (type.FullName == name)
                {
                    var form = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(name)) as Form;
                    return form;
                }
            }
        }
            return null;

    }
```