# open specific windows form using database value in textbox in c#

Tags: c#

I have 3 existing windows forms
Now i want to type the existing windows form name in the textbox and it will display on the screen.
The textbox value come from database column.
How will i do that please help.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: I haven't done anything right now.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open form by string name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522945/how-to-open-form-by-string-name)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed im talking about to display existing form with the base of  database value in textbox ..and the link u mentioned is about string.

Comment: You stated: *"The textbox value come from database column"*. Last time I checked, *"The textbox value"* **is a string**. If you mean something else, you need to clarify your question.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed i want to open an existing form with the base of database value .For example i have a value in database table called Code1. now i want to type Code1 in textbox .and that textbox search Code1 Value in DB then Open the existing Form which match to the Code1 is displayed on the screen. the above link u have mentioned is not working in this case..

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I have made the assumption that the forms are in the same namespace as the one that is trying to call them. It is important to validate any input from the user because there could be typos in there.

Try the following code...

```
var thisType = this.GetType().ToString();
var nameSpace = thisType.Substring(0, thisType.LastIndexOf('.') + 1);
try
{
    var form = Activator.CreateInstance(this.GetType().Assembly.FullName, nameSpace + textBox1.Text).Unwrap() as Form;
    form?.Show();
}
catch
{
    // Chances are there is no such form.
}
```

I would also suggest another strategy, since you suggest a database may have these values, I would rather load the names into a combo box, while also having stored the full name, including the namespace and then create and show the form from that instead of user input.