# C# loading a form from a file

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I'm making a program that lets you open any form in a folder in the project, by clicking its name in a listview.

My problem is that I can't seem to find a way to load/create a Form from a file/FileInfo Object

I'm wondering wether there is a better way to load the forms in to a list, that would make it easier to load a form?

PS: The point is to not know the form names in advance, or have to do any code to be able to open the form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1 {
public partial class FolderList : Form {
    FolderReader fr;
    List<FileInfo> fileList;


    public FolderList() {
        InitializeComponent();
        fr = new FolderReader();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        this.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        this.AutoSize = true;
        this.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;

        fileList = fr.Read();

        foreach (FileInfo file in fileList) {
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(file.Name);
            item.Tag = file;
            LVApps.Items.Add(item);
        }


    }

    private void HandleDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        ListViewItem selected = LVApps.SelectedItems[0];
        FileInfo fi = (FileInfo)selected.Tag;

        //Here i would like to open a form from the file given above

        Debug.WriteLine(fi.Name);
    }
  }
}
```

Folder reader :

```
public List<FileInfo> Read() {

        String dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        dir = dir.Substring(0, dir.Length - 9);
        dir = dir + "Forms";

        Debug.WriteLine(dir);

        List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(dir);
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles("*.cs");
        foreach (FileInfo file in files) {
            if (!file.FullName.Contains("Design")) {
                fileList.Add(file);
            }

            return fileList;

        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: When you say Form did you mean a full pledge windows form ?  If so I think it is impossible to load it from the file. Let's say you have a form1.cs file. You will not be able to load this from a file. Once the application was build. It will become a .exe and all of .cs are compiled.

Comment: Yes, should have mention this is never meant to be build, it's meant to hold small projects, that can fit in 1 form, instead of making new projects for each small test or simuler.

Comment: Ah Sorry, It seems I get it wrong. You want to load the files gracefully. I think making a asynchronous method that fetch the files from directory will be good. Unlike in form load it will not block the ui thread. And while doing so you can show a little spinner or loader when fetching the files

Answer (score 2):

This looks to be what you are looking for:

> var form = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType("WindowsFormsApp1." +
>   fi.Name)) as Form; form.ShowDialog();

from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37523007/7911333